# How to get timezone in DATE_FORMAT()?

Tags: mysql, timezone, datetime-format

I am new to DATE_FORMAT function of MySQL and trying to convert `2020-11-16T17:28:00.000Z` to `Mon Nov 16 2020 12:28:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` in the SELECT query.

I tried `DATE_FORMAT(processDate,'%a %b %e %Y %T') as processDate` which gives `Mon Nov 16 2020 12:28:00`

What are the ways I can include `GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` using DATE_FORMAT() function?

Comment: Shown value is not valid MySQL date literal. YOU must convert it from string to datetime firstly.

Comment: Maybe if you start by showing us the schema definition for the `processDate` column  as well as an acurate example of its contents the question will be clearer, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no DATE_FORMAT() code for timezone, because timezone isn't encoded in the date value.

You can do this:

```
mysql> select concat(date_format(processDate, '%a %b %e %Y %T'), @@session.time_zone) as processDate;
+--------------------------------+
| processDate                    |
+--------------------------------+
| Mon Nov 16 2020 17:28:00+00:00 |
+--------------------------------+
```

But that's the timezone of the MySQL session, not of the date value. Again, the date value does not encode any time zone.